# Is there a way to jump straight to the NppExec Console for inputs via keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: java, notepad++

I'm completely new to programming and I started using Notepad++ to learn java. Is there a way to jump straight to the NppExec Console for inputs without having to use my mouse (i.e keyboard shortcuts)?

I know this seems like an irrelevant question to experienced programmers, but is there a shortcut for me to just jump to the NppExec console without having to use my mouse?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same question, and it turned out that answer is easy to find.
Hot key is just located in NppExec menu: Ctrl+~.